# Local files inside solution folder path issue

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have created a WPF project and added a "ResFiles" folder to my solution. Inside this folder I have put couple of XML files. In code, to access these files I am using relative path as described below.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"../../ResFiles/xyz.xml"))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, mydata, ns);
        }
```

This is working fine. But when I create setup project for my app, the folder structure is changing and the path given wont work. It is throwing file not found exceptions. How to tackle this path issue?

Comment: How about always using Environment.CurrentDirectory as base?

Comment: In solution I have MySolution->MyProject->ResFiles->xyz.xml path. When I install the app the path is MyProject->ResFiles->xyz.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
 var f = File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + @"/Files/file.txt");
```

and also you need to change Build Action and Copy to Output Directory[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try these

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

or

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,@"ResFiles\xyz.xml")
```